# ASP.NET C# SignalR - two different client roles

Tags: signalr

I am currently working on an ASP.NET MVC (with SignalR) project using C# on server side and JavaScript on client side. I want to make one client the master client who can manage the screens of the other clients, i.e. deciding which topic is to be voted for, follow the polling on his screen, be able to open and close the voting procedure etc. All the other clients do only have ONE screen, i.e. the one with the agenda point title and three voting buttons and a submit button.
The problem I encounter here is that I will then have two different clients with their own distinct screens. 
What can I do using SignalR to create these two different clients, let's say an admin and councillers? 
Thanks a lot !

Eric

Comment: signalR group will

Comment: You can create two different hubs on the server. The non-admin client will connect to one while the admin will connect to the other one or both. You may also want to introduce authorization to prevent regular clients try to connect to the admin hub. Alternatively you can have one hub with multiple hub methods some of them only to be used by regular clients while the other by the server.